# VBA - Range: "Run-time error '91'

Tags: excel, range, vba

If the workbook isn't saved and closed and reopened,
I get the following error

> "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block not set"

I have the exact same code (only the name of the string is different) on other places, and sometimes it gives me the same error until I save close and reopen and re-run. Afterwards, the code runs smoothly.

Any ideas on how to avoid the bug? Have you had this problem before?

```
Dim fal As Excel.Worksheet
Set fal = wb.Sheets("Falancs")

Dim x As String
x = "F_1 ="

Dim cc As Integer ' The column as an integer (cc = 1,2,3...)
cc = fal.UsedRange.Find(x).Column
```

Error is on the last line, where the "(x)" is ...

Comment: What does `wb` refer to?

Comment: you should add check for case when value of `x` not found: 1) `Dim res as Range` 2) `set res = fal.UsedRange.Find(x)` 3) `If Not res is Nothing then cc=res.Column`

Comment: it refers to "ThisWorkbook"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Find` returns `Nothing` if value of `x` not found, so you should check it:

```
Dim fal As Excel.Worksheet
Set fal = wb.Sheets("Falancs")

Dim x As String
x = "F_1 ="

Dim cc As Integer ' The column as an integer (cc = 1,2,3...)
Dim res As Range

Set res = fal.UsedRange.Find(x)
If Not res Is Nothing Then
    cc = res.Column
Else
    MsgBox "Value " & x & " not found"
    Exit Sub
End If
```